# nested aliases in /etc/aliases: which order?

Tags: linux, email, alias

my /etc/aliases (ubuntu 12.04 lts) already contains some aliases redirecting to root:

```
postmaster: root
clamav: root
monit: root
```

now I want to add another alias that redirects all root messages to the user mainuser, because root doesn't check its email regularly:

```
root: mainuser
```

does this work? 
does it matter whether the new alias is added at the top of the file or at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order doesn't matter for postfix or exim, but it may matter for other mail servers.